# Simple function/apply combo not working

Tags: r

```
feat_88 feat_89 feat_90  target
    1      0       0    Class_1
    0      2       3    Class_1
    0      0       0    Class_2
    2      1       0    Class_2
    0      0       1    Class_3
    0      2       0    Class_3
    0      23      2    Class_3
```

Hello. Need to group by class then count the number of zeros for each feat_ variable. For feat_88, the result should be 1 for class 1, for class 2 should be 1, and for class 3 should be 3.

The actual data set has 144000 cols and 94 rows. For some reason my code is only working for certain cols; it is saying some cols have no zeros when they obviously do. It is also working correctly for some cols. It is not working for the first two cols then works for a column then does not work for 6 cols then works again. I tried this

```
Count0s<-function(x){                #function that counts zeros in a row

x<-ifelse(x==0,1,0)
x<-sum(x)
numzeros<-x
return(numzeros)
}

go1=apply(subset(Pds[,1:94],target=="Class_1"),2,function(x) Count0s(x))
```

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ target, data=dat, FUN=function(x) sum(x==0) )` might be simpler and give you a nicer output.

Comment: apply is for arrays/matrices. since you have a string column in your data (target), the entire matrix gets converted to character. use `lapply(Pds[, 1:94], Count0s)`

Comment: What does the .~ do. I see this alot and it looks like it is very useful. Thelatemail, your way is awesome. Please explain; when and how can you use it. Can you refer me to a site with a good explanation? Thanks alot.

Comment: rawr, how can i get your code to group by class

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do grouped operations. The packages `dplyr` and `data.table` have excellent support for grouped operations. And in base R, you can use `aggregate` to do grouped operations. Which one you should use depends on your style. Oftentimes the `dplyr` solutions are easier to read and the `data.table` solutions are faster.

```
# base R solution
aggregate(. ~ target, data=dat, FUN=function(x) sum(x == 0)) 

# dplyr solution
require(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(target) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(. == 0)))

# data.table solution
require(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x == 0)), by = target]
```